# Two status panels inside a status bar, how to make sure they are always each taking half of the status bar?

Tags: winforms, statusbar

I have two ( or generally, `n` number of) status panels inside a status bar.

That status bar will always get resize defining on the hosting Windows Form size.

Now, how to make sure that each ( or all of the `n` number of ) status panels get equally amount of width of the status bar, and how to make sure that they are stacking up nicely from left to right as indicated in their order in the `Panels` object?

Answer (score -1):

Just add a function to resize the panels to the `Resize` event on your form.  For two panels, you would just need to add something like this to your form's initialization function to handle the resize.  (Using C#)

```
//To find to width of each panel, subtract 30 (or so, but your panels need to leave a little
//space) from the width of the form, and then divide by number of panels.

//Initialize the panel widths (If they aren't correct already)
statusBarPanel1.Width = statusBarPanel2.Width = (Width - 30) / 2;

//Make the panel widths update if the form is resized
Resize += (s, e) => statusBarPanel1.Width = statusBarPanel2.Width = (Width - 30) / 2;
```

The order of the panels shouldn't change, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: I tried your suggestion by manually setting the panel widths at form constructor and at the Form Load event, neither works.

Comment: It works in my testing.  You're also setting the widths in the Form Resize event, right?